# Set_no_wait not setting a value for a Text field

Tags: ruby, automation, set, watir

We just migrated to the latest version of WATIR(4.0.2), and the method `set_no_wait` does not set a value to the text field.

The text field where I set a value triggers a pop up, and--hence on using the `set` method-- it sets the field but I am not able to control the pop up.

My code looks like this:

```ruby
$b.goto "URL" <br/>
sleep 2 <br/>
$b.text_field(:id, "v1d1perc").set_no_wait "abc"<br/>
```

The above code does not set the field, and hence the pop up will not appear.

But, when I use `set`:

```ruby
<br/>
$b.text_field(:id, "v1d1perc").set "abc".` <br/>
```

It sets the value and the pop up appears, but it hangs there & the next line of code will never be executed. That is, it I have to manually close the pop up to execute next line.

Also, I checked the [Javascript Dialogs](http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/) methods, but it did not work for me, coz as mentioned it never executes the second line until i close the pop up manually.

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of your previous question - [Set\_no\_wait does not set a value for text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359892/set-no-wait-does-not-set-a-value-for-text-field)

Comment: The answer to that question did not help me. And its not allowing me to add any more comments to my own question. Apart from creating one more new post I really did not have a choice.

Comment: Are you sure? From what I have read, you should always be able to comment on your questions.

Comment: Yes am Sure. It did not allow me to add comment. So I typed in the above code in the answer block & addressed it the user who asked me to provide more information on this. Later my answer was removed (for obvious reasons), since my answer was my question!!!  So I added a new question here.